# Filter object properties based on another object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two objects `object_a` and `object_b`. From `object_a` I need only the items whose `ID` appears in `object_b`

```
const object_a = {
    100: "Stack Overflow",
    101: "MDN Web Docks",
    102: "Javascript"
}

const object_b = {
    0: {
        id: 100,
        name: "Stack",
        lastname: "Overflow"
    },
    1: {
        id: 101,
        name: "Web",
        lastname: "Docks"
    }
}
```

From these I need to get all the items in `object a` whose `id` appears on `object b`

```
const desired_object = {
    100: "Stack Overflow",
    101: "MDN Web Docks"
}
```

Comment: And the problem/question is? The simplest approach would be two `for...in...` loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may expand `Object.entries()` of `object_a`, filter out (using `Array.prototype.filter()`) those, that are not seen (`Array.prototype.some()`) among `Object.values()` `id` of `object_b`:

```js
const a = {100:"Stack Overflow",101:"MDN Web Docks",102:"Javascript"},
      b = {0:{id:100,name:'Stack',lastname:'Overflow',},1:{id:101,name:'Web',lastname:'Docks',}},
    
    result = Object.fromEntries(
      Object
        .entries(a)
        .filter(([key]) => 
          Object
            .values(b)
            .some(({id}) => id == key)
        )
     )
    
console.log(result)
```

Another approach (which, I guess, may work slightly faster) could be using `Array.prototype.reduce()` to traverse `Object.keys()` of `object_a` and performing the same check:

```js
const a = {100:"Stack Overflow",101:"MDN Web Docks",102:"Javascript"},
      b = {0:{id:100,name:'Stack',lastname:'Overflow',},1:{id:101,name:'Web',lastname:'Docks',}},
      
      result = Object
        .keys(a)
        .reduce((acc, key) => {
          if(Object.values(b).some(({id}) => id == key))
            acc[key]=a[key]
          return acc
        }, {})
          
console.log(result)
```